# Hippo CMS 7.9 Facets

Tags: facet, hippocms

I'm trying to implement facets and also create a catalog component.

My original approach was to use the:
org.onehippo.cms7.essentials.components.EssentialsContentComponent

However it doesn't seem like it's available for 7.9.
My next approach is to extend the PresentationList Component however the documentation isn't that clear of creating the values for the main and sub categories.

I would like to use this code for my component I'm just not sure once again where to place my Category (values).

```
        try {
        HstRequestContext requestContext = request.getRequestContext();
        HippoBean scope = requestContext.getSiteContentBaseBean();
        PresentationPageableListInfo info = getComponentParametersInfo(request);
        LandingPage presentationPage = null;
        String resolvedContentPath = PathUtils.normalizePath(requestContext
                .getResolvedSiteMapItem().getRelativeContentPath());

        createAndExecuteSearch(request, info, scope, (BaseFilter) null,
                null, resolvedContentPath);

        if (scope instanceof HippoFolderBean) {
            presentationPage = getFirstLandingPageInFolder(request,
                    (HippoFolderBean) scope);
        }

        if (presentationPage != null) {
            request.setAttribute("document", presentationPage);
        }

        if (request.getPathInfo().toLowerCase().contains("facet/")) {
            request.setAttribute("faceted", true);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new HstComponentException("Failed to query presentations.", e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried these pages :
http://www.onehippo.org/7_9/library/concepts/faceted-navigation/faceted-navigation-configuration.html
http://www.onehippo.org/7_9/library/setup/hst-components/facets-component.html

Comment: Works on my machine :P . Do neither of the following work for you ? http://www.onehippo.org/7_9/library/concepts/faceted-navigation/faceted-navigation-configuration.html http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/faceted-navigation/faceted-navigation-configuration.html